# Facebook Webhook Messenger get Page ID

Tags: json, api, facebook, error-handling, messenger

I'm using Facebook's messenger webhook and listening API which also sometimes might respond (bot).
It is important to determine which page ID the webhook is coming from (because it will be used by some pages). From my understanding I've tried to search the params, headers and body.

Am I supposed to decrypt the **X-Hub-Signature** to determine data which might light to the page ID?

Here are the headers:

```js
{
   "Host":"**xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xx-x-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.ngrok.io**",
   "User-Agent":"facebookexternalua",
   "Content-Length":"308",
   "Accept":"\/",
   "Accept-Encoding":"deflate, gzip",
   "Content-Type":"application\/json",
   "Facebook-Api-Version":"v12.0",
   "P-Mi-Om":"FgIA",
   "X-Forwarded-For":"**xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xx::face:b00c**",
   "X-Forwarded-Proto":"https",
   "X-Hub-Signature":"sha1=**xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx**"
}
```

Response:

```js
{
   "object":"page",
   "entry":[
      {
         "id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "time":1636101951119,
         "messaging":[
            {
               "sender":{
                  "id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
               },
               "recipient":{
                  "id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
               },
               "timestamp":1636101950853,
               "message":{
                  "mid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  "text":"hey"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: No, of course you are not supposed to "decrypt" that signature - because that is a technical impossibility to begin with, it's a _hash_ value. _"Here are the headers"_ - and the _data_, is in the body ...

Comment: Added the response body. No page ID here...

Comment: It should be either the sender or receiver id, no?

Answer (score 0):

It is in the response by, as the `recipient` `id` variable.